# Lynx / Elinks alternative for Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a text based browser available for Windows Powershell. An alternative for the *nix based lynx or elinks application?

Comment: No. There is nothing like that.

Comment: What's wrong with Lynx? It works with Windows and thus Powershell by extension. I even use it and wrote a Stack Exchange API-powered site specifically for it: [Column 80 - Plain Text optimised SOFU](http://stackapps.com/q/542)

Comment: Really? Never even thought of  it that there was a dos port for lynx. Totally the way to go, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Powershell is a scripting language.  If your aim is to grab html from a site and parse it in powershell then run get-help invoke-webrequest.  That will suit your needs there.  If your aim is to view web pages like lynx just install lynx on your windows machine.  Another alternative that may work is the dead simple web browser.

https://code.google.com/p/dswb/

Please update this question and let us know what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to accomplish is webbrowsing, but that should be evident. More precise, I want to download various MS evaluation iso to install some software without a GUI.

Comment: If that is the case you want to to script out downloads using powershell.  Look into System.Net.WEbClient .NET object to accomplish this. http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2006-how-to-download-a-file-from-the-internet-with-windows-powershell/